# Paint or white-wash fire-place

Tags: brick

Our fireplace has a fan to turn on to blow hot air out a strip of vertical  bricks (no grout) will this get too hot and ruin paint or whitewash?  The fans are disabled but this area still gets hot. Which would be better to use, if any, paint or white wash?

Comment: Depends on how hot is hot. If you can leave your hand on it for a few minutes, it should be okay.

Comment: And you can always get high-temp paint.